# How can I use a boost function to transform the parameter types?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function

I want to create a boost function object of the following signature:

```
void (int, boost::uuid);
```

However, I would like to bind it to a function of the following form:

```
void (SomeType, boost::uuid)
```

Where the SomeType argument comes from another function call, so that if I were to call it straight out it would look like:

```
SomeType myOtherFunction(int);//Prototype 
... 
myFunction(myOtherFunction(int), myUUID);
```

In other words, I want the top level function object to completely hide the concept of SomeType *and* the call to myOtherFunction from the user. Is there a way to do this with one or more boost::function objects created with boost::bind calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional composition: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5857771eab49eb3d)**

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>

struct SomeType {};
SomeType myOtherFunction(int) { return SomeType(); }
void foo(SomeType, boost::uuids::uuid) {}

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::function<void(int, boost::uuids::uuid)> composed;

    composed = boost::bind(foo, boost::bind(myOtherFunction, _1), _2);
}
```

Anyways, in c++11 you'd write `[](int i, uuid u) { return foo(myOtherFunction(i), u); }` of course